# An error occurred while copying a file into an archive folder

Tags: gnome, 13.04, java, archive

I am trying to drag .png files into a folder in a .jar archive. The error additionally occurs with .zips as well. I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on an ext4 filesystem with default filemanager for gnome-shell.

I have tried various archive managers to get this to work and none seem to cooperate. Talking on IRC, this apparently is not a common problem and none knew the answer. I'm just trying to add textures into a Minecraft.jar without having to extract and compress again (which is completely possible with 7zip in Windows).

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: It doesn't give a specific error. All I am given is: "An Error Occurred"

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074166), it is a known bug of `file-roller`. Try to downgrade your package ([see here](http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/)) and put it on hold to prevent future upgrading.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out the proper way to do this with the required dependencies. Could you provide me a commandline walk-through to install a working version?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use 13.04... :(